# Create a particular type of link between two WorkItem's in TFS using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am creating test cases (`Test Case` type of task) in PowerShell and I am trying to link them to a story (`Product Backlog Item`) as "Test Cases" and not as ordinary links.

Suppose `$WIT` is the WorkItemStore and `$testcaseId` and `$storyId` are valid IDs.
If I do:

```
$testCase = $WIT.GetWorkItem($testcaseId)
$workitem.Links.Add($storyId)
$workitem.Save()
```

I will have a bunch of "normal" links from the test case to the story, which is not what I want.

In C#, this seems to be achievable by creating a new `RelatedLink` and specifying the type of the link. Here's a snippet ([more info here](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2013/01/17/Creating-a-linked-Workitem-via-the-TFS-API.aspx))

```
source.Links.Add(new RelatedLink(linkTypeEnd, approval.Id));
```

Is there any way to do the same in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in Powershell the same way that you do it in C#... that's the awesome power of PowerShell :)

```
[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Hyperlink]$NewLink = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Hyperlink -ArgumentList $newlocation
$wit.Links.Add($NewLink)
```

I first use the PowerShell function above to pull in the relevant DLL's then I have access to the Above is the code to create and add a new Hyperlink. From this you should be able to easily create other types of links.

Comment: Awesome indeed. Just for reference, here's what I ended up with, following your suggestion: `[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.RelatedLink]$NewLink = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.RelatedLink -ArgumentList ($WIT.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds["Test Case"], $validId)`